# Merge Sort copy the rest of the first half

Tags: java, mergesort

The merge sort algorithm has a part looks like this, when it merges two arrays:

```
while (fromValue <= mid && middleValue <= to) {
  if (comp.compare(a[fromValue], a[middleValue]) < 0) {
    values[index] = a[fromValue];
    fromValue++;
  } else {
    values[index] = a[middleValue];
    middleValue++;
  }
  index++;
}

while (fromValue <= mid) {
  values[index] = a[fromValue];
  fromValue++;
  index++;
}
while (middleValue <= to) {
  values[index] = a[middleValue];
  middleValue++;
  index++;
}
```

I understand the first while statement. But whats the point of the second and the third while statement. Because for the first while to stop, "fromValue > mid" and "middleValue > to" already. So those two other while statements will be skipped?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an Case example array of: `{2, 4, 7, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6}`

The first while loop copies the sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` at which point `middlevalue` has reached `to`. So, the loop ends.

The program then moves to the first of the remaining while loops which copies in the values `7, 9`.

Case example 2, take array: `{4, 7, 8, 10, 5, 6, 12, 14}`
Here the main while loop copies in `4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10` at which point `fromValue` has reached `mid`. So, the loops ends.

The program then moves to the second of the remaining while loops which copies in the values `12, 14`.

Thus, only one (which one depends on the initial array) of the two smaller while loops is skipped.